# Procedimiento con cursores Oracle

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, stored-procedure, plsql, cursor

Tengo este procedimiento hecho, pero en un departamento no hay empleados y quiero que dentro de ese departamento me muestre un mensaje, y no logro conseguirlo. Lo he probando haciendo un IF y tambien con una EXCEPTION pero no logro hacerlo.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE infodept
AS
CURSOR dept IS SELECT dept_num,dept_nom from dept;
vdept dept%ROWTYPE;
CURSOR empl IS SELECT empl_num,empl_nom,empl_ofici from empl where empl_dept_num=vdept.dept_num;
vempl empl%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
OPEN dept;
    FETCH dept INTO vdept;
    WHILE dept%FOUND LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vdept.dept_num||' - '|| vdept.dept_nom);
        OPEN empl;
                FETCH empl INTO vempl;
                WHILE empl%FOUND LOOP
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('        '||vempl.empl_num||' - '||vempl.empl_nom||' - '||vempl.empl_ofici);
                FETCH empl INTO vempl;
                END LOOP;
        CLOSE empl;
    FETCH dept INTO vdept;
    END LOOP;
CLOSE dept;
END;
```

Este seria el resultado de mi codigo, como veis, debajo del ultimo departamento no me muestra nada, ahi quiero que salga: 'Este departamento no tiene empleados.'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Puedes agregar el `IF` después de que obtienes los valores con el `FETCH` y verificando si tienes valores con el `ROWCOUNT`

```
FETCH empl INTO vempl;
IF empl%NOTFOUND THEN //Comparas si es vacío
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No encontrado');
ELSE
    IF empl%ROWCOUNT=0 THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Este departamento no tiene empleados.');
    ELSE 
        WHILE empl%FOUND LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('        '||vempl.empl_num||' - '||vempl.empl_nom||' - '||vempl.empl_ofici);
        FETCH empl INTO vempl;
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
END IF;
```